# error find symbol in R.id. when build android cordova app

Tags: android, angular, mobile, webview, native-code

Good day,

I would like to set the `allowFileAccess` to true in WebView websetting.

I try to do something as follow:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

When I try to build my app, I hit the `error: cannot find symbol`.
[image]

Its pointing to the `R.id.`, may I know what mistake I did?

The full error is as follow:
[image]

I am fresh to frontend, and never try native code before.

Or is there any other place I can do for this other than Activity.java?

Comment: can you show error? Do you have `webview` id in your layout? From which package did you import `R` ?

Comment: Hi @AmmarAbdullah, I am new to frontend development, may I know where can I get my layout to check the webview id?
I import R in `package de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.receiver;`